# Can specific text be made read-only in Code Mirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using Code Mirror to create a simple HTML tutorial for beginners. I'd like to allow users to edit the text between tags, but not to edit the tags themselves.

For example, in this bit of code:

```
<p>Some inner text</p>
```

...users should be able to delete the inner text, but not the opening or closing tags.

Is it possible to define read-only text like this by setting Code Mirror properties, or will I have to do some custom post-processing of the user input?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I know and reading the docs for my editor it is ***not*** possible to do this. You will have to some extra stuff. Sure, you could put a positioned div on top, but, it isn't the best practice.